# Spring Security Authorization - Admin is denied access

Tags: spring, security, spring-mvc, spring-security

The authorization for the role admin is being denied access to the whole system - the admin and home pages. So I added ROLE_ADMIN to the /main/home intercept-url.

This is the security xml

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">

<intercept-url pattern="/**" requires-channel="https" />
<intercept-url pattern='/main/home/' access="hasRole('ROLE_USER' 'ROLE_ADMIN')" />
<intercept-url pattern='/admin/admin/**' access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
<intercept-url pattern='/main/user/setter/settingpage' access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
<intercept-url pattern='/main/user/setter/addpage' access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
<intercept-url pattern='/login.jsp' access='IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY' /> 

<form-login login-page="/login.jsp" default-target-url="/main/home" authentication-failure-url="/auth/loginfail?error=true"/>

</http>
```

But that made the whole program stop working as When I run the code as it is the error is

> Failed to parse expression 'hasRole('ROLE_USER' 'ROLE_ADMIN')'

When I do remove the `ROLE_ADMIN` the system works and can authenticate users just not the `ROLE_ADMIN` who is now being denied access to all pages. In the db I have set up the roles and it was working until recently.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As the error message indicates,

> Failed to parse expression 'hasRole('ROLE_USER' 'ROLE_ADMIN')

You need to use `hasAnyRole()` with a comma separated list of authorities.

> Returns true if the current principal has any of the supplied roles
>   (given as a comma-separated list of strings), [see](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html)

So change

```
<intercept-url pattern='/main/home/' access="hasRole('ROLE_USER' 'ROLE_ADMIN')" />
```

to

```
<intercept-url pattern='/main/home/' access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ADMIN')" />
```

---

Since, you have set `use-expressions` to true, you need to change

```
IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY
```

to

```
isAnonymous()
```

Answer (score 0):

**SpEL: Spring Expression Language**

```
access="hasRole('ROLE_USER') and hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"
```

also:

```
access="hasRole('USER_ADMIN') and hasIpAddress('192.168.1.10')"
```